# When chaining firstOrCreate() and with(), Eloquent query returns unexpected results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

A beginner question... I have the following Eloquent query. It returns me a collection of `Sheets` instead of just one `Sheet` which seems wrong - the documentation for `firstOrCreate()` says it will return the first row, not a collection:

```
// Original query which returns a collection instead of first row
$sheet = Sheet::firstOrCreate(["user_id" => $userId, “date" => $date])->with(“post.tags", “post.categories", “meta")->get();
```

If I remove the `with()` then I get just one sheet as expected, but I am missing my extra data:

```
// I get one Sheet as expected but I am missing my extra data
$sheet = Sheet::firstOrCreate(["user_id" => $userId, “date" => $date])->get();
```

I can fix it by using `first()` instead of `get()`, but this seems wrong:

```
// Works but seems like the wrong fix    
$sheet = Sheet::firstOrCreate(["user_id" => $userId, “date" => $date])->with(“post.tags", “post.categories", “meta")->first();
```

The reason it seems wrong is that I am effectively specifying "**get the first row**" twice in the query builder. I'm not sure why adding `with()` makes `firstOrCreate` return a collection instead. Is there something I am doing wrong in my syntax or is this just a Laravel quirk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're chaining methods like this, you need to be aware what each of the methods you're calling actually returns.

Here is a little bit of a breakdown:

```
// your original statement
$sheet = Sheet::firstOrCreate(["user_id" => $userId, "date" => $date])
    ->with("post.tags", "post.categories", "meta")->get();

// is equivalent to this:

// this creates an instance of Sheet
$sheet = Sheet::firstOrCreate(["user_id" => $userId, "date" => $date]);

// this calls with() on the Sheet instance, which returns an Eloquent Query Builder
$sheet = $sheet->with("post.tags", "post.categories", "meta");

// this calls get() on the Query Builder, which returns a Collection of Sheets
$sheet = $sheet->get();
```

Hopefully that should spread some light on why you were getting a Collection.

For your original question, though, since you already have the instance after the call to `firstOrCreate()`, all you're really looking to do is load the relationships for it. You can do this using the `load()` method:

```
$sheet = Sheet::firstOrCreate(["user_id" => $userId, "date" => $date])
    ->load("post.tags", "post.categories", "meta");
```

Use `with` when you're using the query builder. Use `load` when you already have an instance and you want to eager load the relationships for it.